# How to fix: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) PCA

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, scikit-learn-pipeline

I have two variables:

```
numeric_cols = ['FamilyMembers', 'ChronicDiseases']
```

and I have this pipeline:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
                        steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler(),
                                'red_dim', PCA())
])
```

and I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I get the same error with 4 variables.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline's `steps` should be a list of (name, transform) tuples as follows:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
                        steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                                ('red_dim', PCA())
                              ]
)
```